# R - return string within first set of quotation marks

Tags: r, string, substring, quotations

SO I have a dataframe made up of thousands of records that I have imported from .csv. One variable within the dataframe is a free text field dervied from a lexicon. The rows of data are in the below format.

Please note that the below are not vectors but rows of char data within a variable 'date' (they just happen to look exactly like a vector):

```
c("9th november 2018", "27th october 2018"),

c("three months", "6 months"),

c("24th december ", "2th january 2019", "25th january 2019")
```

essentially all that I am interested in doing is taking the string from the first set of quotation marks and removing the rest, so:

```
c("9th november 2018", "27th october 2018") 
9th november 2018
```

I am using the following code but it is taking the string from the last set of quotation marks:

```
LexiDate3$finaldat3 <- sub('.*,"*(.*?) *" *', '\\1', LexiDate3$Date_new)
```

which returns:

```
27th october 2018")
```

Not ideal and for the life of me cant figure this one out. Any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the input. You are trying to process a text file with data that just happens to look like R code? And you're trying to parse it with regular expressions? This seems odd.

Comment: My guess is that OP used a sub-optimal method to import data and the strings show up as vectors in the data.frame. A solution would be to import it correctly.

Comment: Actually, if the problem is what @avid_useR says, the simplest solution would be to just do `LexiDate3$finaldat3<-LexiDate3$Date_new[1]` to grab the first item in every vector of Date_new.

Comment: I am importing from .csv, the data is taken from a lexicon that looks at a free text field taken from another system within the company to deduce the date, however if more than one date has been identified is spits it out in the above format . This will form part of an automated process so will need to be done in R then re exported as a .csv and fed back into our BI system. A fun task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does this look?  Note the quotes around the output are put there by the print method and not embedded in the string.

```
library(stringr)
test <- 'c("9th november 2018", "27th october 2018"),'
str_extract(test,'(?<=")(.*?)(?=")')
#> [1] "9th november 2018"
Created on 2019-02-21 by the reprex package (v0.2.1)
```

Comment: Art, thank you sir that worked a charm. The dataframe variable actually contained a large number of character strings that were not in the c("... format and returned nulls for this. However I overcame this issue bu creating a final date column with the following:  LexiDate3 <- LexiDate3 %>%
  mutate(finaldate = coalesce(finaldat3, Date_new))